# Twitter cards with buttons

Tags: twitter, twitter-card

I want to integrate the functionality just like 
https://twitter.com/BlackLifesMater/status/904648980750934016 on my twitter account how i will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the API response:

```
"id_str": "904648980750934016",
    "text": "I think Conor McGregor would beat Floyd Mayweather. Cast your vote now! https:\/\/t.co\/03uRV5SIrl",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/03uRV5SIrl",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/cards.twitter.com\/cards\/18ce54fgl4f\/47kog",
            "display_url": "cards.twitter.com\/cards\/18ce54fg\u2026",
            "indices": [72, 95]
        }]
    },
```

That's a Twitter card.  I suspect that it's a specific advertiser card - you can see some of them at https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-setup/advertiser-card-specifications.html